# Feature selection using leave one out regression results

Tags: regression, feature-selection, scikit-learn

Disclaimer: I'm a basic scientist who only starting to dabble in ML

I saw a presentation today where the presenter did feature selection by identifying the variables that resulted in a univariate linear regression with a p < 0.05 for all iterations of a leave-one-out. I'm curious how this leave-one-out style of feature selection compares to using the [f_selection](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.f_regression.html#sklearn.feature_selection.f_regression) with [SelectKBest](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest.html#sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest) function in sklearn, which lists its procedure as:

1. The correlation between each regressor and the target is computed,
       that is, ((X[:, i] - mean(X[:, i])) * (y - mean_y)) / (std(X[:, i])
       * std(y)).
2. It is converted to an F score then to a p-value

Comment: As a side note, p-values are not meant to be used for feature selection. And doing it as the presenter did it, by including only variable at a time, she did not account for the possible interactions / confounders / controls...

Comment: Thanks for your comment. As I've been poking around this forum more, it seems like the presenter took an unconventional approach